# JQUERY/JavaScript - call to custom math function not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that passes values into another function to perform calculations. I rewrote it from jquery into pure js on account of performance issues existing. The function has multiple for loops and is a bit odd to understand. Basically it starts at a column index (19) and gathers cells starting at the top and once they reach the cell below with the class of subtotal they average the values and return.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/2azzqeh9/17/)

Function that calls the average function:

```
$(function doIt() {
   var el1 = $('#rackPlan1 > thead > tr > th:gt(17):not(.totalRow)');
   var x = el1.length;
   var starter = 19;
   for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
     var divs = $('#rackPlan1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')');
     for (var a = 0; a < divs.length; a++) {
       var thisDiv = divs[a]; // element
       var $thisDiv = $(divs[a]); // jquery object 
       getAverage($thisDiv, 'subTotal');
     }
     starter += 1;
   }
 })
```

The calculations perform on the cells with the header of Proto A, B, etc. So for instance for bottoms in Proto A the third cell down what should be returned is 1.0 (the average) instead of 0.

Comment: First: Did it work with jQuery? Second: You still have jQuery code in there. Anything with `$` is jQuery. Third: How do you call this?You have it wrapped in parenthesis. Normally functions in parenthesis also have `()` at the end, meaning the function gets called immediately

Comment: First: Yes it worked but the performance was terrible. Second: Yes I am aware of that but I basically changed .each() to for loops which fixed the performance problem. Third: Yes it gets called at DOM ready